# Andengine set OntouchEvent to child sprite

Tags: android, andengine

Class ToolBar extends Sprite and this class has buttons;

```
class ToolBar extends Sprite(){
    private Sprite button;
    public ToolBar(ITextureRegion toolbarimg,ITextureRegion buttonimg ,VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager){
        super(0,0,toolbarimg,pVertexBufferObjectManager);
        button = new Sprite(0,0,buttonimg,pVertexBufferObjectManager){
          @Override
          public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float X, float Y) {
          .....
        }
        this.attachChild(button);
    }
}
```

The button is appear on ToolBar sprite.

My question is how to register touch event to button sprite.
In this case , i cannot use ***Scene.registerTouchArea*** method.
How can I register event in this case?
Do I have to pass Scene object to this Class and register to scene?

Comment: Why don't you just set the touch on toolbar directly? It extends sprite after all.

Comment: why cant you use Scene.registerTouchArea?

Answer (score 0):

You  can do this do this by registering the toolbar as a touchArea, and then you override the onAreaTouched method to survey if any of your buttons are in the point clicked.

```
// In your ToolBar class:

@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    final float[] touchAreaSceneCoordinates = this.convertLocalCoordinatesToSceneCoordinates(pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
    final float touchAreaSceneX = touchAreaSceneCoordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_X];
    final float touchAreaSceneY = touchAreaSceneCoordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_Y];

    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
        for (Button button: this.buttonsInYourToolBar) {
            if (button.contains(touchAreaSceneX, touchAreaSceneY)) {
                button.onPressed(); // deal with the click inside your Button class
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```